# On hover, li items should take full height of the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to make the `li` elements tall as the height of the `header`.

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYJzjZ?editors=110)**

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow;
  height: 7.5vh;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.navigation li:hover {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Logo</h1>

  <nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: is there some reason your not toggling the `background-color` ?

Comment: @JordanDavis - No, it works better for me the debugging process on a bright color.

Comment: No I mean why are you toggling the height of the element, why don't you just toggle/change the background color of the element on `:hover`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to utilize the `line-height` property and make it the same as the `height` you defined for your `<header>`:

```
.navigation li:hover {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 7.5vh;
}
```

Here's an updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojLGRB). Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -2):

Add `display:block` in `.navigation li:hover`.

Comment: It would be helpful to include a working example in your post.

Comment: That won't be necessary.